# DirectShow CSourceStream::FillBuffer unpredictable number of calls after Pause and Seek to the first frame

Tags: c++, directshow, source-filter

I have a Directshow File Source Filter which has audio and frame output pins. It is written in C++ based on this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758088(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN. My filter opens the video by using [Medialooks MFormats SDK](https://www.medialooks.com/mformats/?utm_expid=385009-1.puXcDO7HQROiNOwT2T-iJA.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.medialooks.com%2Fproducts%2F) and provides raw data to output pins. Two pins are directly connecting to renderer filters when they are rendered.

The problem occurs when I run the graph, pause the video and seek to the frame number 0. After a call to `ChangeStart` method in output frame pin, sometimes `FillBuffer` is called three times and frame 1 is shown on the screen instead of 0. When it is called two times, it shows the correct frame which is the frame 0.

Output pins are inherited from `CSourceStream` and `CSourceSeeking` classes. Here is my `FillBuffer` and `ChangeStart` methods of the output frame pin;

#### FillBuffer Method

```
HRESULT frame_pin::FillBuffer(IMediaSample *sample)
{
     CheckPointer(sample, E_POINTER);

    BYTE *frame_buffer;
    sample->GetPointer(&frame_buffer);

    // Check if the downstream filter is changing the format.
    CMediaType *mt;
    HRESULT hr = sample->GetMediaType(reinterpret_cast<AM_MEDIA_TYPE**>(&mt));
    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        auto new_width = reinterpret_cast<VIDEOINFOHEADER2*>(mt->pbFormat)->bmiHeader.biWidth;
        auto old_witdh = reinterpret_cast<VIDEOINFOHEADER2*>(m_mt.pbFormat)->bmiHeader.biWidth;

        if(new_width != old_witdh)
            format_changed_ = true;

        SetMediaType(mt);
        DeleteMediaType(mt);
    }

    ASSERT(m_mt.formattype == FORMAT_VideoInfo2);

    VIDEOINFOHEADER2 *vih = reinterpret_cast<VIDEOINFOHEADER2*>(m_mt.pbFormat);

    CComPtr<IMFFrame> mf_frame;

    {
        CAutoLock lock(&shared_state_);

        if (source_time_ >= m_rtStop)
            return S_FALSE;

        // mf_reader_ is a member external SDK instance which gets the frame data with this function call
        hr = mf_reader_->SourceFrameConvertedGetByNumber(&av_props_, frame_number_, -1, &mf_frame, CComBSTR(L""));
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return hr;

        REFERENCE_TIME start, stop = 0;

        start = stream_time_;
        stop = static_cast<REFERENCE_TIME>(tc_.get_stop_time() / m_dRateSeeking);

        sample->SetTime(&start, &stop);

        stream_time_ = stop;
        source_time_ += (stop - start);

        frame_number_++;
    }

    if (format_changed_)
    {
        CComPtr<IMFFrame> mf_frame_resized;
        mf_frame->MFResize(eMFCC_YUY2, std::abs(vih->bmiHeader.biWidth), std::abs(vih->bmiHeader.biHeight), 0, &mf_frame_resized, CComBSTR(L""), CComBSTR(L""));
        mf_frame = mf_frame_resized;
    }


    MF_FRAME_INFO mf_frame_info;
    mf_frame->MFAllGet(&mf_frame_info);

    memcpy(frame_buffer, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(mf_frame_info.lpVideo), mf_frame_info.cbVideo);

    sample->SetActualDataLength(static_cast<long>(mf_frame_info.cbVideo));
    sample->SetSyncPoint(TRUE);
    sample->SetPreroll(FALSE);

    if (discontinuity_)
    {
        sample->SetDiscontinuity(TRUE);
        discontinuity_ = FALSE;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

#### ChangeStart Method

```
HRESULT frame_pin::ChangeStart()
{
    {
        CAutoLock lock(CSourceSeeking::m_pLock);
        tc_.reset();
        stream_time_ = 0;
        source_time_ = m_rtStart;
        frame_number_ = static_cast<int>(m_rtStart / frame_lenght_);
    }

    update_from_seek();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft DirectShow documentation:

> The [CSourceSeeking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/csourceseeking) class is an abstract class for implementing
>   seeking in source filters with *one* output pin.
>
> CSourceSeeking is not recommended for a filter with more than one
>   output pin. The main issue is that only one pin should respond to
>   seeking requests. Typically this requires communication among the pins
>   and the filter.

And you have *two* output pins in your source filter.

The CSourceSeeking class can be extended to manage more than one output pin with custom coding. When seek commands come in they'll come through both input pins so you'll need to decide which pin is controlling seeking and ignore seek commands arriving at the other input pin.

Comment: I already took into account what you propose here. I let the frame pin handle seek signals and notified audio pin when start changed from frame pin. Are you suggesting that because I have multiple pins, FillBuffer method is called more than what is expected?

Comment: That does seem entirely possible. Have you look at the call stacks for the calls to FillBuffer? You may find it easier to build the baseclasses library with symbols and reference it as a subproject for ease of debugging, rather than just a prebuilt library. I find stepping through and looking at the source code of baseclasses vital for DirectShow development, rather than treating it as a static 'black box'.